# Topologically homogeneous space?

Tags: gn.general-topology

I want to know an example of a topological space $X$ which satisfies the following.

- for all points $x,y\in X$ and neighborhoods $U_x$, $U_y$, there exist neighborhoods $U'_x\subset U_x$, $U'_y\subset U_y$ of $x$ and $y$ that are homeomorphic (the homeomorphism does not have to map $x$ to $y$).
- $X$ has some kind of good conditions, i.e Hausdorff, locally connected, locally compact, second countable, etc.
- **X is not locally Euclidean ** (i.e., not a topological manifold)

I can't find the good example.

---

In fact, one goal of my question is this:
"How can I make locally euclidean property from other topological properties."

Comment: Reminds me of uniform spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space 


Comment: Your edit "How can I make locally euclidean property from the other topological properties" should properly be posted as a new question (fleshed out a little).

Comment: @Kim, in the literature what you're asking for *would* be called a manifold in the literature.  Take a google scholar search of "fractal manifold".  Things that look locally like a Sierpinski gasket would be Sierpinski gasket manifolds.  FYI it doesn't take much to make the Sierpinski space into a locally homogeneous space I believe removing the three extremal vertices should do the job.

Comment: Ryan, the factoid about Sierpinski gasket doesn't sound right: isn't it the case that it has points of ramification index 2,3,4?

Comment: In Kim's definition the homeomorphism between the neighbourhood U of x and V of y does not have to send x to y. At least, it's not written that way. 

Comment: Ok, I was thinking of a stronger version of local homogeneity. BTW, a standard trick is to glue two copies of the Sierpinski gasket along the 3 exterior vertices. This produces a $\textit{compact}$ "Sierpinski gasket manifold" which is almost homogeneous (the automorphism group has 2 orbits).

Comment: @RyanBudney if the homeomorphism doesn´t have to send x to y then any space would have that property: take U=V=X.

Comment: @Ramiro de la Vega: That is a good point! Since the goal is to have a local condition, this can be fixed by modifying "open neighborhoods" with "arbitrary small". I agree that the fomulation in the question is sloppy, though.

Comment: I've fixed the definition to take Ramiro's issue into account. The question was visibly written sloppily anyway, it's possible that the OP really wanted to map $x$ to $y$ but doesn't seem to be prone to clarify. Also it's not clear whether $U_x$, $U_y$ should be assumed open, this may affect the definition a bit.

Comment: @VictorProtsak I think you're mistaken about the automorphism group of the Apollonian gasket.  I believe the automorphism group is countable (indeed, it is a free product with amalgamation of two finite groups), so it must have uncountably many orbits.  The argument is that there are only countably many triples of points whose removal disconnects the gasket, and any homeomorphism of the Apollonian gasket is entirely determined by its restriction to one such triple.

Comment: @YCor, I agree with Ramiro's issue. But  your editing seems to also have the same issue. If one can choose $U_x=U_x'=X=U_y'=U_y$ then any space X satisfies the property what I wanted. I think that  we essentially need to the codition of local homeomorphism that maps $x$ to $y$.

Comment: @SeonhwaKim of course not, because the condition is that this holds for all $U_x$ and $U_y$. For instance, the disjoint union of a point and a segment does not satisfy this homogeneity property. Also the Stone-Cech boundary of $\mathbf{N}$ satisfies this homogeneity property but is not homogeneous.

Comment: @JimBelk That's a nice argument, Jim! I am no longer sure what I meant by that homogeneity remark. The stabilizer of a disconnecting triple is a cyclic group of order 2 rather than trivial, though (a nitpick).

Answer (score 7):

An infinite dimensional torus $X = \prod_{n=1}^\infty S^1$ has all these properties.  It's a topological group, so certainly homogeneous.  It is compact, metrizable, connected, locally connected, and second countable.  But it is not locally Euclidean.

Comment: The infinithe dimensional torus is an infinite dimensional manifold, i.e locally R^infinity. 

In a certain sense, It is also locally euclidan.

Comment: @Seonhwa Kim: X is not locally Euclidean if endowed with the product topology, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology . The point is that a basic open set is a product of open sets $U_i$, only a finite number of which are different from $S^1$. The topology you have in mind is too fine and would not be compact. 

Comment: @ Benoît Kloeckner: thank you for good point. but I think that it depends on what is the meaning of infinite dimensional "locally euclidean".  I think it means usually infinite dimensional vector space or function space. and that has product topology or compact-open topology. I have known that the infinite dimensional torus with product topology is an an infinite dimensional manifold. 
I'd like to find the example which is not manifold. 

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that, but I figured this answer would at least force you to clarify :)  Indeed, I think you should try to state precisely what you mean by "infinite-dimensional manifold" since there are several notions.

Comment: @Seonhwa Kim: Nate Elredge is right to ask you for clarification, it seems to me that even infinite-dimensional, a manifold should be locally homeomorphic to some topological vector space. I hardly want to call a space, each open set of which has a non-finitely generated fundamental group, a manifold.

Comment: Also, the infinite dimensional torus is not locally $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ or any other infinite dimensional topological vector space, since it is locally compact.

Answer (score 3):

The  $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ provides an example that is locally connected but not locally compact.

Proof. We need to show that the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ is acting transitively on $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$. The idea is to conisder piecwise linear automorphisms of  $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ with rational coefficients with infinately many breaks.

In order to explain how this works we will conisder the $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and prove the statement here. Let $x$ and y be two points in $\mathbb R\setminus  \mathbb Q$. Then conisder two  monotonly decresing (for $i\ne 0$) seuqences of rational numbers $x_i$, $y_i$, $i\in \mathbb Z$ with $x_0=x$, $y_0=y$,  with 
$lim_{i\to + \infty} x_i=x$, $lim_{i\to + \infty} y_i=y$ and $lim_{i\to - \infty} x_i=x$, $lim_{i\to - \infty} y_i=y$. Finally take the piecwise linear map from  $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ to itself that sends $x_i$ to $y_i$. This is the automorphism we a looking for. 
In the case of  $\mathbb R^2\setminus \mathbb Q^2$ the same thing can be done by chosing anappropriate triangulations of $\mathbb R^2$.

I don't see how to make a locally compact set.

Answer (score 3):

This [survey paper](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~repovs/clanki/published/halverson1.pdf) on the Bing-Borsuk conjecture may be useful.

Comment: Very good survey!

Answer (score 2):

A *homogeneous continuum* is a compact connected metric space X such that for any two points x,y there is a homeomorphism of X taking x to y. This obviously implies that X is locally the same everywhere (*a priori*, it is a stronger condition). There are plenty of examples in books on general topology. My favorite one is a [solenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_%28mathematics%29), which is not a manifold because, for example, it is not locally connected.

**ADDENDUM** The Menger curve C (also known as the Menger sponge, Menger universal curve, and Sierpinski universal curve) is a one-dimensional locally connected continuum. R.D. Anderson proved a characterization which implies that C is n-point homogeneous and that, moreover, up to a homeomorphism, the circle and C are the only one-dimensional homogeneous locally connected continua.

Anderson, R. D. *A characterization of the universal curve and a proof of its homogeneity.* Ann. of Math. (2) 67 1958 313-324 [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=96180)

Anderson, R. D. *One-dimensional continuous curves and a homogeneity theorem.*
Ann. of Math. (2) 68 1958 1-16 [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=96181)

By the way, I am not a general topologist: all information can be easily found using web searches starting with "homogeneous continuum".

Comment: I have pointed that "locally connected" property. The examples of homogeneous continuum in wikipedia "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology)"; are locally euclidean or not locally connected. and the examples like topologist's sine curve what I know is also not locally connected. As wikipedia, Peano continuum is locally connected homogeneous continuum, but I can not make the concrete example too. – Seonhwa Kim 28 secs ago

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the "locally connected" assumption (you may want to make your requirements on X more explicit, instead of including them as an afterthought). I can think of two negative results: $$ $$
(1) Masurkiewicz proved that a locally connected homogeneous planar continuum is a Jordan curve; $$ $$
(2) Bing and Borsuk proved that an n-dimensional homogeneous continuum that is an absolute neighborhood retract (ANR) is a topological manifold for n=1,2. Apparently, it's unknown whether this remains true for higher n.

Comment: The Menger curve is a very good example indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the locally connected assumption, the middle third Cantor set satisfies the desired properties. The proof can be given as in Nate Eldredge's answer, since it is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Hilbert cube $\,\ \mathcal H\ :=\ [0;1]^\mathbb N\,\ $ is a homogeneous space and it seems beautiful to me (it's compact, connected, locally connected, contractible, it's an absolute retract, ...).

The Hilbert cube decomposes into a cartesian product in a great variety of ways.

Oh, by the way, $\ \mathcal H\ $ is not locally Euclidean nor locally Hilbert (no infinite-dimensional compact is).

Comment: Is it obvious that it's homogeneous?

Comment: @YCor Homogeneity of HQ is not obvious, it is a theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/why-is-the-hilbert-cube-homogeneous) for references.

Comment: Thanks! Note that the fact it satisfies the weaker homogeneity (apparently) asked by the OP is much easier: indeed it's immediate that every point of $\mathcal{H}$ has a basis of neighborhoods all homeomorphic to $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: @YCor, construct a homeomorphism which maps $p$ to pseudo-interior (the rest is obvious). Let $\ k\ $ be the first index for which $\ p_k\in\{0\ 1\}\ $ (or else we're done). Rotate sq. $ [0;1]^{\{k\ k\!+\!1\}}\ $ so that the $k$-th coordinate $\notin \{0\ 1\} $ (the two coord's of the image of $p$ move within the border of the sq. away from $\ \{0\ 1\}\times[0;1].\ $ Now, repeat it for the first border coord. of the image, say $p_n\ $ (by necessity, $k<n$). Etc. This procedure ends in or converges to a homeomorphism -- the image of $p$ will belong to the pseudo-interior.